# Get original URL in a callback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Assuming that I'm talking about an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, the scenario is something like

1. I browse to the URL `http://localhost:60088/Example?param1=test123` that returns a view
2. Next I click a button that triggers an Ajax call to the URL `http://localhost:60088/Example/DoSomethign` that returns a JSON string

So, my dilemma is that in the `DoSomething` controller action I need to get the `param1` parameter that was passed in the first step.

My first take is to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    ...

    Uri baseUrl = this.Request.UrlReferrer;
    // Somehow extract the parameter from baseUrl

    ...
}
```

But I'm not sure if that's a good idea at all...

**Questions:**

1. Is safe to assume that `this.Request.UrlReferrer` will **always** have the URL that was called in a non-callback way (even if I made several more callbaks after the `_DoSomething_` first callback)?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish waht I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; you cannot assume that the referrer will always exist.

Instead, you should include the original URL as a parameter in the AJAX request.

Comment: :( ... I suspect that will be the answer. Sadly I need to do this in several different callbacks across the applicattion, so probably I'll end persisting the parameter on the session object... Anyway I'll leave the question unaswered to see if other ideas arose

Answer (score 0):

In your action that returns the view, you could add the `param1` to a `ViewBag`, something like this:

```cs
public ActionResult Example(string param1)
{
    ViewBag.Param1 = param1;
    return View();
}
```

Then in the ajax call, just pass the `ViewBag.Param1` as a route value. It may sometimes be empty, but that shouldn't hurt anything.